# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "cdKDropList"

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I have imported DragDropModule into my lineups module which houses the component I am using the drag drop feature on:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HometeamComponent } from './hometeam/hometeam.component';
import { AwayteamComponent } from './awayteam/awayteam.component';
import { LineupsComponent } from './lineups.component';
import { AwayteamService } from './awayteam/awayteam.service';
import { HometeamService } from './hometeam/hometeam.service';
import { NationalityService } from './nationality.service';
import { PositionsService } from './positions.service';
import { NgxSmartModalModule } from 'ngx-smart-modal';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { PlayerComponent } from './player/player.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxSmartModalModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DragDropModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HometeamComponent,
    AwayteamComponent,
    LineupsComponent,
    PlayerComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AwayteamService,
    HometeamService,
    NationalityService,
    PositionsService
  ],
  exports: [
    HometeamComponent,
    AwayteamComponent
  ]
})
export class LineupsModule { }
```

For safe measure, I imported it into the module above that and also just to be sure, I imported it into app.module.ts - but with the following code, I get this error:

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "cdKDropList"
```

**component.html code**

```
<div class="players">
<span
cdKDropList
#fullSquad="cdKDropList"
[cdkDropListData]="players"
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="selectedTeam"
(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <h5 [style.font-family]="config.header_font.data.font_family">Full Squad</h5>
  <ul *ngFor="let player of players" cdkDrag>
    <app-player 
    [player]="player" 
    [config]="config" 
    (openModal)="editPlayer($event)"></app-player>
  </ul>
</span>
```

```
<div class="players selected" 
    *ngIf="startingPlayers"
    [cdkDropListData]="startingPlayers"
    #selectedTeam="cdKDropList"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="fullSquad"
    (cdkDropListDropped)=”drop($event)”
    >
    <h5 [style.font-family]="config.header_font.data.font_family">Starting XI</h5>
    <ul *ngFor="let player of startingPlayers; let i = index">
      <li>
        <ng-container *ngIf="i == 0"><img src="../assets/img/goalie-shirt.svg" alt="goalkeeper shirt"></ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="i !== 0">
          <svg [style.fill]="'#' + config.club_shirt.data.hex_code" id="shirt" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
            <defs></defs>
            <path id="path854" class="cls-1"
                  d="M19.25,1a5.15,5.15,0,0,0-1.15.18,12.94,12.94,0,0,1-4.12,0c-1.1-.27-1.56-.24-2,.13A14.87,14.87,0,0,1,9.83,2.38C6.85,3.64,6.17,4,5.36,4.81a3.76,3.76,0,0,0-1,1.42,38.4,38.4,0,0,0-1.05,5C3,13,3,12.94,5.92,13.91a6.9,6.9,0,0,0,2.1.47h.72l-.07,5.15c0,2.9-.15,6.33-.26,7.82a12.84,12.84,0,0,0-.08,2.94c.17.38.82.52,3,.64s9.51,0,11-.12,1.54-.06,1.36-3.12a113.21,113.21,0,0,1-.31-12.79l.08-.55.44.05a13.14,13.14,0,0,0,4.77-1.56c.3-.3.26-.78-.27-3.69-.41-2.21-.76-3.3-1.28-4s-1.95-1.56-4.31-2.56a17.9,17.9,0,0,1-2.63-1.29A1.26,1.26,0,0,0,19.25,1Z" />
          </svg>
        </ng-container>
        {{ player }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h5 [style.font-family]="config.header_font.data.font_family">The Bench</h5>
    <ul *ngFor="let player of theBench; let i = index">
      <li>
        <ng-container *ngIf="i == 0"><img src="../assets/img/goalie-shirt.svg" alt="goalkeeper shirt"></ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="i !== 0">
          <svg [style.fill]="'#' + config.club_shirt.data.hex_code" id="shirt" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
            <defs></defs>
            <path id="path854" class="cls-1"
                  d="M19.25,1a5.15,5.15,0,0,0-1.15.18,12.94,12.94,0,0,1-4.12,0c-1.1-.27-1.56-.24-2,.13A14.87,14.87,0,0,1,9.83,2.38C6.85,3.64,6.17,4,5.36,4.81a3.76,3.76,0,0,0-1,1.42,38.4,38.4,0,0,0-1.05,5C3,13,3,12.94,5.92,13.91a6.9,6.9,0,0,0,2.1.47h.72l-.07,5.15c0,2.9-.15,6.33-.26,7.82a12.84,12.84,0,0,0-.08,2.94c.17.38.82.52,3,.64s9.51,0,11-.12,1.54-.06,1.36-3.12a113.21,113.21,0,0,1-.31-12.79l.08-.55.44.05a13.14,13.14,0,0,0,4.77-1.56c.3-.3.26-.78-.27-3.69-.41-2.21-.76-3.3-1.28-4s-1.95-1.56-4.31-2.56a17.9,17.9,0,0,1-2.63-1.29A1.26,1.26,0,0,0,19.25,1Z" />
          </svg>
        </ng-container>
        {{ player }}
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

If I remove the following:

```
#fullSquad="cdKDropList"
[cdkDropListData]="players"
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="selectedTeam"
```

it allows me to reorder just one list and I want to be able to drag items from one list to another. Following this [tutorial](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-drag-and-drop-with-the-angular-material-cdk-2e0237857290) - the error shows up.

Not sure why it's not working and the previous issues shown on SO, show that the DragDropModule isn't imported which, in mine, it is.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having the exact same problem, and with this post, at least I know I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Got to import the browserModule

```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

  imports: [
             .... //other modules
             BrowserModule
           ]
```